# appending binary data to file in c

Tags: c, file, io, binary, append

I open a file in C and perform a CRC32 algorithm on the data. From this I get a checksum which I now want to append to the file so that the bit-code of the int is at the end of the bitcode of the file. But when I write the integer to the file all numbers are interpreted as chars and not the bitcode of the int is written. So I tried this:

```
    int r, tmp, sum3; 
    for(r = 0; r < 25; r+=8){
        int s;
        sum3 = 0;
        for(s = r; s < r+8; s++){
            tmp = 1;
            int v;
            if(binzahl2[s] == '1'){ //binzahl2 contains the bitcode of the checksum as char array
                for(v = 7; v > s-r; v--)
                    tmp*=2;
                sum3 += tmp;
            }
        }
        int y=fprintf(file, "%c", (char) sum3);
    }
```

But of course every time sum3 is greater than 127 there's a problem with the cast to char so that as first digit of the byte is written 0 and not 1.

Is there any way to fix this so that the 1 is written at the beginning of the byte?
Or is there (hopefully) a better way to append the right binary data?

Comment: An example of the file input and desire file output would help clarify your problem and goal.

Comment: The input is just a .txt file with something like "This is a test." The output doesn't matter, it doesn't have to make sense. It's just important that the bitcode of the integer is appended at the end of the bitcode of the file so that i can run the crc32 algorithm again and check if everything is correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);

fwrite("\n", sizeof(char), 1, file);

char binzahl2[33];
unsinged int checkSum; //some value you have calculated
unsinged int b = 1;

for(i = 31; i > -1 ; i--){
    if( checkSum & (b << i) ){binzahl2[31 - i] = '1';}
    else{binzahl2[31 - i] = '0';}
}

binzahl2[32] = 0;

size_t charCount = strlen(binzahl2);

fwrite(binzahl2, sizeof(char), charCount, file);
```

Comment: I already tried it but when i write it to the file the numbers get interpreted as chars and it's wrong again

Answer (score 0):

`fprintf` is for outputting formatted data (that's what the f at the end stands for). You want to use `fwrite` instead.

Comment: I already tried fwrite but there was the same problem like I already mentioned: everything I write to the file gets interpreted as char and the wrong bitcode is appended

Comment: Can you express that with different words? What's "bitcode"? Byte data? If so then that's what files contain, a string of bytes. And in your other comment, "the bitcode of the integer is appended at the end of the bitcode of the file", again, files are strings of bytes. A byte is a number between 0 and 255 for reference.

Comment: for example when the file looks like this when i print every bit: 10001000110000101110011001000000110100101110011011101000010000001100101011010010110111000100000010101000110010101110011011101000010111000110011001110010011000100110001001101100011001000110010001100100 and the checksum like this: 00000010010101001101110110111110
I want to append the checksum at the end

Comment: So write it using `fwrite`. What's the issue?

Comment: I have a .txt file which contains "This is a test." I have the checksum which is a unsigned int. And I have created a char array which contains the checksum binary. Now I don't want the checksum to appear in the file what happens when I use fwrite, I want to add the bits of the checksum to the bits of which the file consists.

Comment: Are you talking about.. alternate data streams?.. Where would the information go if not in a file?